# Can I make get a small local array in registers?

Tags: gcc, llvm, compiler-optimization, cpu-registers, stack-frame

I may be forced to write some performance-critical C/C++ code involving several input arrays and a result array (never mind the exact types). For certain reasons I'd like to work on small chunks of my output array, modifying them according to the inputs - but without constantly reading and writing them back to memory, since I don't trust the cache (that is, I'm worried the input arrays will overwrite it, and I'll end up actually doing memory read and writes, which is horrendous...) so, I was thinking of playing it safe and trying to stay on registers.

- Can I get a small, local, fixed-length array to be stored in registers only?
- How do I achieve this?
- How big can such an array be (say, on a Haswell or Skylake core)?

Comment: Can't you use non-cache-polluting reads and such? Anyway you can't reasonably do this (it can be done, just not reasonably, you won't like it) unless all the indexes are constant, and then it's really not an "array in registers" but just business as usual, keeping stuff in registers while you're operating on it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, no. Most CPU architectures don't provide any way to index into registers, so there would be no way to access your data as an array. (On ARM, for instance, there are registers `r1` through `r15`, but there is no way to directly access a register by its number. The same applies to x86.)

Your concerns about cache eviction are probably misplaced. Modern CPU architectures are generally pretty good at managing the cache.

Comment: What if the number of iterations for all loops is known in advance? i.e. one could map all array elements to registers without having to address a register by its number at run-time?

Comment: @einpoklum Maybe, but you'd have to unroll the loop. Depending on your application, this may hurt performance overall more than it helps.

Comment: Ah, the question is whether the _compiler_ can unroll the loop.